# Flicker images when I load new items in recyclerview

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to load online images to ImageView in android and all it works correctly. But when I try to load more items into the recyclerview, all the loaded imageviews do a little flicker.

This is the basic code:

```
Ion.with(holder.thumbnail).load(album.getImageSmall());
```

How I can stop this flicker?

Answer (score 0):

That is default item change animation of recycler view and also a known [**bug**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177517#c2) .
Try setting animation duration to 0

```
recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
```

You can further look into this thread for this matter

[RecyclerView blinking after notifyDatasetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331075/recyclerview-blinking-after-notifydatasetchanged/32227316#32227316)

I am not marking this question as duplicate as there is no accepted answer.