# WebView in RecyclerView will flash when notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview

I have a `WebView` in my `RecyclerView`, whenever I call `RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged` the `WebView` will have a short flashing.

I don't want any changes happen on the `WebView`, how can I do this ?

I know I can solve this with using `notifyItemXXX` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`. But I do need `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Comment: Can you keep track of the webView index and use notifyItemRangeChanged?

Comment: @AlokOmkar I can keep the `WebView`'s trace, but the `notifyDataSetChanged` is the simplest way to refresh the dataset.  If I use `notifyItemRangeChanged`, I need to do a lot of work on my app's logic.

Comment: To prevent flashing effect, check out this SO Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32488059/2648035 - let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the
[notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) official doc says "LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views.". So I think the webview's flash is caused by this. And you can find this "Rely onnotifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.".
As you mentioned you must use this method, so can you please give more info so I can help you to find out a better solution.

Comment: It seems that If I use `notifyDataSetChanged`, the `webView` must flash. I need `notifyDataSetChanged` because it's the simplest way to refresh the dataset. My `RecyclerView` includes a lot of different types of entries,  after a response from the server, some need to be deleted, some need to be added in, some need to refresh and some do nothing. Really hard to use `notifyItemXXX`.

Comment: An other question, can I use both `notifyItemRangeRemoved` and `notifyItemRangeChanged` at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `notifyItemRangeRemoved` and `notifyItemRangeChanged` at the same time, but be careful about the range. As the `notifyItemRangeRemoved` says " The items previously located at and after positionStart + itemCount may now be found at oldPosition - itemCount."

Comment: There seems to be no other way, I will use `notifyItemRangeXXX` to do this. Thanks for your answer, and I will accept it.