# How to make specified item not update when notifyDataSetChanged in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a item in `RecyclerView` which does not need to be updated when I call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

But I didn't find any methods to make the specified item avoid updated.  Is it possible to do this ?

---

I need to do this because the item is a `WebView`, it had loaded a html page, if I called `notifyDataSetChanged`, this item will flash.

The reason why I post this question is avoiding the flash of the `WebView` when `notifyDataSetChanged` (see [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626466/webview-in-recyclerview-will-flash-when-notifydatasetchanged)). After the failure of using `notifyItemRangeXXX` methods, I post this question.

But after checking your answers and comments, it seems that it's impossible to avoid updating when using `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: if you don't want it update, dont change the datasource

Comment: If viable, you can also use `notifyItemChanged(pos)` for others except the item in question.

Comment: If you're usign RecyclerView.Adapter. You might want to consider notifyItemChanged(int position), notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `notifyDataSetChanged` IS to update ALL items. Don't use it if you don't want this behavior!

The correct approach would be to only update the data you've changed. There are some methods which will help you to only invalidate the desired data:

```
notifyItemChanged(int position)
notifyItemInserted(int position)
notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
notifyItemRemoved(int position)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, its actually possible to do so. `notifyDataSetChanged()` notifies the RecyclerView that **all the elements in the data set has changed**.

As you do not want that to happen and exclude specific items.

```
for(int i = 0; i< mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++){
    if(i != itemPositionToExclude){
       mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
}
```

So, we need to loop through all the elements in the adapter and call `notifyItemChanged()` only for those positions `which you do not want to exclude`.

Answer (score 1):

You should think in different way - which items need to be updated. To update UI of item, after data has changed use method [notifyitemchanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))